# Every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is generated by at most two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove

> Every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be generated by at most two elements.

Since I have not seen any prime ideal generated by 3 elements, this statement seems true to me. But I cannot find a way to prove it. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Hint: for any prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field; hence, $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]$ is a PID. Likewise, $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is also a PID. Take any prime ideal $P \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$, and consider $Q := P \cap \mathbb{Z}$. Since $Q$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, it is generated by either $0$ or a prime number $p$. If $Q = p\mathbb{Z}$, try to use the cited fact about about $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]$. If $Q = \{0\}$, try the same with $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is more "things that work in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$"
 more than "general algebraic methods", but it works.)

Suppose you have three (or more) generators.  Then either two of them are constants or two of them are polynomials (of positive degree).  With what can you replace these two generators?  (Hint:  Same answer for both cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could I ask why either two of them are constant or two of them are polynomials,

Comment: @LevBan Another way to look at a constant is as a polynomial of degree $0$.  The degree of a generator is a non-negative integer.  So either two generators have degree $0$ or two generators have positive degree.

Comment: @LevBan : Pigeonhole principle.  There are two pigeonholes: constants and polynomials.  Every element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is one or the other.

Comment: @EricTowers  Thank you so much! So in the case when there are two constants, we can replace it with the gcd of them. As for when we have two nonconstant polynomials we mod the ideal out by appropriate prime ideal as the comment of Alex then we get the PID so we can reduce the ideal generated by  two polynomials into the ideal generated by one polynomial.  Is it correct so far?

Comment: @LevBan : In the two polynomial case, we can also replace them with their (polynomial) gcd.  (Which is what you said, but perhaps obscuring that this parallels the two constants case.)

Comment: @EricTowers  My concern is if there is $gcd$ of two polynomials. Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a Euclidean domain, it is not necessary to have gcd of two arbitrary polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$. So in my solution in the comment, I actually don't know how to bring the gcd in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. :( Could you give me more clarification?

Comment: @LevBan : Being a ED is too strong.  Every ideal in an ED is principal.  However, you should know how to compute polynomial GCDs in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, since this application of Euclid's algorithm is something taught in high school.  It is enough that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD *and* we have a GCD algorithm in the coefficients.

Comment: @EricTowers  Could you help me out to remove my confusion?  So let's consider $(3x+1,x+1,3)$. As you suggested, I choose $3x+1$ and $x+1$. Their gcd should be $1$ by the property of UFD.  By the Euclidean Algorithm, we have $3x+1=3(x+1)-2$ which terminates  the algorithm immediately... So using Euclidean algorithm here does not give good way to compute the gcd.

Comment: @EricTowers Actually, $(3x+1,x+1,3)=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ because $2=3(x+1)-(3x+1)$ so $\mathbb{Z}[x]=(1)=(2,3)\subseteq (3x+1,x+1,3)$.  But if we conclude that the gcd of $x+1$ and $3x+1$ is $1$, without using $3$, we immediately get that the ideal is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So it seems we need more argument

Comment: @EricTowers  Also, we have not used the property of prime ideal here...

Comment: @LevBan : You realize the polynomial GCD algorithm stops as soon as you get a non-polynomial (i.e., not when you get the remainder zero, but when you get a remainder of degree zero -- because you've just shown that the two have no positive degree common divisor).

Comment: This answer doesn't look right: it seems that it works for any ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$, and the ideals of $\mathbb Z[x]$ can have arbitrary numbers of generators.

Comment: Btw, there is no polynomial GCD algorithm in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: Last but not least, I have no idea why the OP, who raised some serious doubts, decided to accept this answer.

Comment: @user26857 : There may be a GCD algorithm in any GCD domain.  $\Bbb{Z}$ is a UFD, so $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD.  All UFDs are GCD domains.  This shows there is a GCD and LCM in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.  The algorithm generating [primitive pseudo-remainder sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Primitive_pseudo-remainder_sequence) computes such GCDs.  It is not the only such algorithm.

Comment: This is not the main question here (and I still believe that the "algorithm" you invoke is useless in this case; more useful could be to consider the polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and clear the denominators then). The problem is that your answer fails to produce  two generators as in the trivial case of the ideal $(2,x,x+2)$. Moreover, even if your process would be correct (but once again, it is not!) how do you know that every prime ideal has a finite number of generators?

Comment: @user26857 : It is not required that it produce two generators for the ideal you write.  It is only required that it produce *at most* two generators for every prime ideal.  Further, this Answer is responsive to the Question, not, as you seem to expect, to the quotation in the Question -- it constitutes the key insight I had in solving this problem largely the same way as in the Answer you reference in your comment to the Question.

Comment: You can't produce two or at most two generators for every prime ideal in the way you suggested. In the example I mentioned I introduced a fake generator and your process fails to produce two or less generators. That's why I said that your suggestion doesn't work and consequently the answer is wrong. I understand that you want to produce a constructive solution, but if there is one then it must take care of all situations.

Comment: @user26857 : Step 1 of Euclidean reduction of the pair $(x+2,x)$ is $(x+2-x, x) = (2,x)$, and the algorithm halts as reminded in comments above.  Replacing that pair in your ideal yields $\langle 2, x, 2 \rangle = \langle 2,x \rangle$.  After denying the existence of the polynomial GCD algorithm, your refusal to understand it is wasting both our times.  Based on your history at MSE, *you* might benefit from this answer re-phrased in terms of S-polynomial reduction as used in Buchberger's algorithm, but such a rephrase does not improve the answer given OP's apparent context.

Comment: If everything is so clear to you, then why don't try to elaborate in such a way that every aspect is covered and finally give a full proof? (For instance, I can't see the Euclidean reduction mentioned so far.) Posting a truncated answer, based on question marks and vague hints, is actually of waste of everyone's time.

Comment: "Why [I] don't" is: (1) OP agrees this Answer resolved his Question, (2) the Question requests "Help", not a full proof, and (3) because the full proof exists elsewhere on MSE.  A Question requesting a full proof would have been a duplicate of the Question you reference in your comments to this Question, so this Question would have been closed as a  duplicate.  However, this Question does not request a full proof, so your comments do not constitute an improvement to this Answer.

Comment: [This recent thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344693) is the living proof that your answer needs an improvement.

Comment: @user26857 : That thread asks for a generalization outside the scope of the Question here.  This answer warns that it is responsive the Question that is actually asked here, not to a more general Question.  Your thread shows that this Answer would not answer *that* Question, but it is not offered as an answer to that Question and is clearly marked to not be a response to the generalization in that Question.

Comment: The other full proof is quite different than yours. Your approach is taking a different route and for some reasons you still prefer to write tones of comments instead of clarifying your answer.

Comment: Come one! What generalization? Everything works similarly for PIDs. You simply refuse to improve your answer.

Comment: You seem to wish that this Answer responded to a different Question or that the Question that was asked were different.  I have patiently explained that both wishes are wrong.  Your comments do not constitute an improvement to this Answer to this Question.

Comment: I have the feeling that we are living in parallel worlds. Let's read what this question asks: "*I am trying to prove Every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be generated by at most two elements.*". Did your answer prove this? I don't think so!