# Prove that every ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be generated by at most two elements of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Prove that every ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be generated by at most two elements of $R$.

$\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried proving it in a more specific case, like for instance quadratic polynomials?

Comment: You added the [tag:model-theory] tag. Are you looking for model-theoretic proof or something? Or did you mean “module theory”?

Comment: What about $\left<X^2,2X,4\right>$?

Comment: If you meant to say "every *prime* ideal", see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317685/every-prime-ideal-in-mathbbzx-is-generated-by-at-most-two-elements?rq=1

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300170/ideals-of-mathbbzx

Comment: Agha Farshad.. koja gir kardi?!